# How to download zip file from tomcat server web app location

Tags: java, tomcat

I am working on ios project. One of the module in that project download *.zip files and extract them into app memory. on the server side I installed tomcat server, and uploaded all *.zip files and some *.txt files to the context path.

But when I call the *.txt file's it's working fine (I am getting text on app and browser) but when I call *.zip's file I got 404 (the requested resource is not available). the url is correct but it's only working for .txt files and some extension files.

I think it's blocking .zip files for security reasons. But I need zip file need to downloaded.

Comment: i am not aware of such behavior by Tomcat, to block a file type, are you sure you are typing the correct file name in the URL? it's case sensitive , file.zip is not same as File.zip

Comment: I don't think that Tomcat blocks zip files, at least not out of the box. Make sure that the files have the proper filesystem permissions to be readable by the user running the Tomcat process.

Comment: Try to add [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

if the .zip files is outside the server webapps path its need to be added on context path (and dir path), and reload the server solves the problem.